# Django: удалить запись после обновления и записать ее в другую модель

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как сделать чтобы при обновлении / редактировании записи из списка, запись удалялась из исходной модели и уже новой, обновленной записывалась в другую модель? Сейчас при обновлении / редактировании записи она просто сохраняет сама себя и отображается в общем списке уже обновленной. Но если я создаю новую запись, она сохраняется корректно в новом списке.

Нужно чтобы при обновлении модели NewAnzeigen создавалась и сохранялась запись в модели Fertig а исходная запись в NewAnzeigen удалялась. Идея в том, чтобы при оброботке исходного списка в NewAnzeigen те записи, которые нужно менять сразу сохранялись в новый список, так сказать на чистовик, а в исходном списки оставались только те записи, которые еще нужно обработать.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import NewAnzeigen
from .models import Fertig
from .forms import NewAnzeigenForm
from django.views.generic import DetailView, UpdateView, DeleteView


class AnzeigeDetails(DetailView):
    model = NewAnzeigen
    template_name = 'main/details.html'
    context_object_name = 'article'


class AnzeigeUpdateDetails(UpdateView):
    model = NewAnzeigen
    template_name = 'main/create.html'

    form_class = NewAnzeigenForm


class AnzeigeDeleteDetails(DeleteView):
    model = NewAnzeigen
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'main/delete.html'


class FertigDetails(DetailView):
    model = Fertig
    template_name = 'main/details.html'
    context_object_name = 'article'


class FertigUpdateDetails(UpdateView):
    model = Fertig
    template_name = 'main/create.html'

    form_class = NewAnzeigenForm


class FertigDeleteDetails(DeleteView):
    model = Fertig
    success_url = '/fertig'
    template_name = 'main/delete.html'


def index(request):
    anzeigen = NewAnzeigen.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'anzeigen': anzeigen})


def fertig(request):
    fertigeanzeige = Fertig.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/ready.html', {'fertigeanzeige': fertigeanzeige})


def create(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewAnzeigenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            error = 'Ooopps.. Fehler...'

    form = NewAnzeigenForm()
    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }
    return render(request, 'main/create.html', data)
```

forms.py

```
from .models import NewAnzeigen
from .models import Fertig
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Textarea, ChoiceField
from django import forms


class NewAnzeigenForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fertig
        RASSEN = (
            ('araber', 'Araber'),
            ('ha', 'Hispano-Araber'),
            ('cruzado', 'Cruzado'),
            ('lustiano', 'Lustiano'),
            ('pre', 'PRE'),
            ('muli', 'Muli'),
            ('esel', 'Esel'),
        )
        FARBE = (
            ('falbe', 'Falbe'),
            ('bucksin', 'Bucksin'),
            ('schimmel', 'Schimmel'),
            ('rappe', 'Rappe'),
            ('schecke', 'Schecke'),
            ('ps', 'Porzellanschecke'),
            ('fuchs', 'Fuchs'),
            ('brauner', 'Brauner'),
            ('champagne', 'Champangne'),
            ('cremello', 'Cremello'),
            ('palomino', 'Palomino'),
            ('tg', 'Tigerschecke'),
        )
        ART = (
            ('fohlen', 'Fohlen'),
            ('stute', 'Stute'),
            ('hengst', 'Hengst'),
            ('wallach', 'Wallach'),
        )
        AUSBILDUNG = (
            ('ungeritten', 'Ungeritten'),
            ('geritten', 'Geritten'),
            ('hs', 'Hohe Schule'),
            ('zucht', 'Zucht'),
        )
        ABSTAMMUNG = (
            ('ja', 'Ja'),
            ('nein', 'Nein'),
        )
        widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        rasse = ChoiceField(choices=RASSEN, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        art = ChoiceField(choices=ART, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        abstammung = ChoiceField(choices=ABSTAMMUNG, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        ausbildung = ChoiceField(choices=AUSBILDUNG, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        farbe = ChoiceField(choices=FARBE, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        fields = ['name', 'beschreibung', 'preis', 'standort', 'telefon', 'alter', 'geschlecht', 'grosse', 'rasse', 'art', 'abstammung', 'farbe', 'ausbildung']
        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Name eingeben'
            }),
            'beschreibung': Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Beschreibung eingeben'
            }),
            'preis': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Preis eingeben'
            }),
            'standort': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Ort / Land eingeben'
            }),
            'telefon': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Telefonnummer eingeben'
            }),
            'alter': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Alter eingeben'
            }),
            'grosse': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Größe in cm. eingeben'
            }),
            'geschlecht': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Geschlecht eingeben'
            }),
        }
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import csv



class NewAnzeigen(models.Model):
    RASSEN = (
        ('Araber', 'Araber'),
        ('Hispano-Araber', 'Hispano-Araber'),
        ('Cruzado', 'Cruzado'),
        ('Lustiano', 'Lustiano'),
        ('PRE', 'PRE'),
        ('Muli', 'Muli'),
        ('Esel', 'Esel'),
    )

    ART = (
        ('Fohlen', 'Fohlen'),
        ('Stute', 'Stute'),
        ('Hengst', 'Hengst'),
        ('Wallach', 'Wallach'),
    )

    AUSBILDUNG = (
        ('Ungeritten', 'Ungeritten'),
        ('Geritten', 'Geritten'),
        ('Hohe Schule', 'Hohe Schule'),
        ('Zucht', 'Zucht'),
    )

    ABSTAMMUNG = (
        ('Ja', 'Ja'),
        ('Nein', 'Nein'),
    )

    FARBE = (
        ('Falbe', 'Falbe'),
        ('Bucksin', 'Bucksin'),
        ('Schimmel', 'Schimmel'),
        ('Rappe', 'Rappe'),
        ('Schecke', 'Schecke'),
        ('Porzellanschecke', 'Porzellanschecke'),
        ('Fuchs', 'Fuchs'),
        ('Brauner', 'Brauner'),
        ('Champangne', 'Champangne'),
        ('Cremello', 'Cremello'),
        ('Palomino', 'Palomino'),
        ('Tigerschecke', 'Tigerschecke'),
    )
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    preis = models.CharField('Preis', max_length=255)
    telefon = models.CharField('Telefon', max_length=255)
    beschreibung = models.TextField('Beschreibung')
    anzeigenummer = models.CharField('Anzeigenummer', max_length=255)
    standort = models.CharField('Standort', max_length=500)
    online = models.CharField('Online seit', max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField('URL', max_length=1000)
    bild = models.CharField('Bild', max_length=1000)
    rasse = models.CharField('Rasse', max_length=255, choices=RASSEN, default='')
    alter = models.CharField('Alter', max_length=255, default=1)
    grosse = models.CharField('Grosse', max_length=255, default=100)
    geschlecht = models.CharField('Geschlecht', max_length=255, default='')
    art = models.CharField('Art', max_length=255, choices=ART, default='')
    ausbildung = models.CharField('Ausbildung', max_length=255, choices=AUSBILDUNG, default='')
    abstammung = models.CharField('Abstammung', max_length=255, choices=ABSTAMMUNG, default='')
    farbe = models.CharField('Farbe', max_length=255, choices=FARBE, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.id}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Anzeige'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Anzeigen'

with open('main/daten.csv', encoding='utf-8') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        _, created = NewAnzeigen.objects.get_or_create(
        name = row[0],
        preis = row[1],
        telefon = row[2],
        beschreibung = row[3],
        anzeigenummer = row[4],
        standort = row[5],
        online = row[6],
        url = row[7],
        bild = row[8]
        )


class Fertig(models.Model):
    RASSEN = (
        ('Araber', 'Araber'),
        ('Hispano-Araber', 'Hispano-Araber'),
        ('Cruzado', 'Cruzado'),
        ('Lustiano', 'Lustiano'),
        ('PRE', 'PRE'),
        ('Muli', 'Muli'),
        ('Esel', 'Esel'),
    )

    ART = (
        ('Fohlen', 'Fohlen'),
        ('Stute', 'Stute'),
        ('Hengst', 'Hengst'),
        ('Wallach', 'Wallach'),
    )

    AUSBILDUNG = (
        ('Ungeritten', 'Ungeritten'),
        ('Geritten', 'Geritten'),
        ('Hohe Schule', 'Hohe Schule'),
        ('Zucht', 'Zucht'),
    )

    ABSTAMMUNG = (
        ('Ja', 'Ja'),
        ('Nein', 'Nein'),
    )

    FARBE = (
        ('Falbe', 'Falbe'),
        ('Bucksin', 'Bucksin'),
        ('Schimmel', 'Schimmel'),
        ('Rappe', 'Rappe'),
        ('Schecke', 'Schecke'),
        ('Porzellanschecke', 'Porzellanschecke'),
        ('Fuchs', 'Fuchs'),
        ('Brauner', 'Brauner'),
        ('Champangne', 'Champangne'),
        ('Cremello', 'Cremello'),
        ('Palomino', 'Palomino'),
        ('Tigerschecke', 'Tigerschecke'),
    )
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    preis = models.CharField('Preis', max_length=255)
    telefon = models.CharField('Telefon', max_length=255)
    beschreibung = models.TextField('Beschreibung')
    anzeigenummer = models.CharField('Anzeigenummer', max_length=255)
    standort = models.CharField('Standort', max_length=500)
    online = models.CharField('Online seit', max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField('URL', max_length=1000)
    bild = models.CharField('Bild', max_length=1000)
    rasse = models.CharField('Rasse', max_length=255, choices=RASSEN, default='')
    alter = models.CharField('Alter', max_length=255, default=1)
    grosse = models.CharField('Grosse', max_length=255, default=100)
    geschlecht = models.CharField('Geschlecht', max_length=255, default='')
    art = models.CharField('Art', max_length=255, choices=ART, default='')
    ausbildung = models.CharField('Ausbildung', max_length=255, choices=AUSBILDUNG, default='')
    abstammung = models.CharField('Abstammung', max_length=255, choices=ABSTAMMUNG, default='')
    farbe = models.CharField('Farbe', max_length=255, choices=FARBE, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.id}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Fertig'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Fertig'
```

Comment: мало инфомарции, какая модель, в какую модель, зачем вообще? нет кода формы...

Comment: Дополнил и описал подробнее

Comment: "чтобы при оброботке исходного списка в NewAnzeigen те записи, которые нужно менять сразу сохранялись в новый список, так сказать на чистовик, а в исходном списки оставались только те записи, которые еще нужно обработать." а почему бы просто не добавить `BooleanField` как флаг того, обработано или нет?

Comment: А как это корректно реализовать с BooleanField чтобы на одной странице отображались все записи с False а на другой с True ?

Comment: дополнил ответ. если он помог и можете отметить его как правильный, если считаете что ответ хорош, то можете дополнительно нажать на стрелку вверх у ответа, дав положительный голос. ну или вниз если ответ отстой)

Comment: Большое спасибо! С BooleanField отлично всё сработало и сократило код. К сожалению из-за моей маленькой репутации мой голос за ваш ответ не учитывается

Comment: ничего, был рад помочь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый быстрый способ - в форме переопределить `save`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    source_instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    new_instance = Fertig()
    for field in [  # поля можно в принципе подтянуть из Fertig._meta.fields или из других св-в Fertig._meta
        'name', 'preis', ..., 'farbe'
    ]:
        setattr(new_instance, field, getattr(source_instance, field, None))
    new_instance.save()
    source_instance.delete()  # или remove, не помню

    return new_instance
```

Но это не совсем правильный вариант, так как вернется объект не того типа, который указан в `Meta` формы.

Чтобы было более корректно, наверное лучше сделать от `Form` класса, или еще как. Либо указать в комменте где то , что вернется объект другого типа, чтобы потом у вас не было проблем с отладкой

---

> А как это корректно реализовать с BooleanField чтобы на одной странице отображались все записи с False а на другой с True ?

Пример модели

```
class ExampleAnzeigen(models.Model)

    class Meta:
        ...


    field1 = ...

    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)  # Для вашего варианта True вроде подходит, db_index для ускорения
    ...
```

На одной странице отображаете `ExampleAnzeigen.objects.filter(is_draft=True)` на другой `ExampleAnzeigen.objects.filter(is_dradft=False)`

Можно вынести в менеджер объектов

```
class ExampleAnzeigenManager(models.Manager):
    def draft_only(self)
        return seflf.filter(is_draft=True)
    def not_draft_only(self)
        return seflf.filter(is_draft=False)


class ExampleAnzeigen(models.Model):
    ....
    objects = ExampleAnzeigenManager()
```

Тогда там где черновики, выводите `ExampleAnzeigen.objects.draft_only()` а на чистовиках `ExampleAnzeigen.objects.not_draft_only()`

Изменить черновик на чистовик - в `save()` формы от `ModelForm`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super().save(commit=False)
    instance.is_draft = False
    instance.save()
    self._save_m2m()
    return instance
```